# Can't setup a namespace in my developer org

Tags: developer-edition

I have a developer org, which was created in 2009 (stating this only in the thought this may be a reason for my issue)
[image]

I am trying to create a namespace now. So, following some articles:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/configure_developer_settings.htm#configure_developer_settings

In the packages, I do not see the 'Edit' button.
[image]

Assuming I have 'done' this in the past, I tried to query for my org's namespace prefix, but nothing:

> ```
> SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization
> ```

Dev Hub is enabled:
[image]

But the result is empty - so I am a bit puzzled.

Any ideas how I can create a namespace prefix ?

Comment: Is the dev hub enabled in the org?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: As mentioned in the page "If the edit button on this page isn’t visible, ensure you’re using a Developer Edition org that isn’t a Dev Hub org." if Dev Hub is enabled you  will not get edit button.

Comment: argh, not sure how I missed that part, thanks. that's the answer....

Comment: I will post the same as Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a namespace the org should  Developer Edition org that isn’t a Dev Hub org.

But as per the screenshot the DevHub is enabled so you may be able to create namespace in that org.